# changing one file in swift causes lots of rebuilds

Tags: xcode, swift, compilation

I'm using Xcode Version 6.3.2 (6D2102) and have problems with my compile times... changing one swift file causes loooots of files to compile as well - what could be the reason for this or how can I debug/track this down?

[image]

Comment: Do u have a lot of if else chaining in the code? I experienced the same problem last time and I just trimmed the code for it to work

Comment: The fact that the files appear in the build log does not mean that they are actually compiled. Compilation could be cached and they are still listed there. Also using ObjC code through bridging header can cause unexpected recompiles. -- If you find no other way around this issue then you should split you project into separate modules. We have a project with 352 Swift files and 69 ObjC files split into 22 modules.

Comment: @fluidsonic it also takes pretty long, therefor I assume the files are really recompiled. What do you mean by splitting up into modules? Libraries?

Comment: @swalkner we split our code into multiple CocoaPods development pods and then plug them all together using the main app's `Podfile`. E.g. `pod 'MixpanelService', :path => 'modules/Services/Mixpanel'` in `Podfile` to import a module containing only code related to Mixpanel tracking. The module will need a simple `.podspec` file and its Swift files. In the app project you can then `import MixpanelService` and use the classes in there as usual.